# Silverlight: Load and bind Xaml dynamically

Tags: .net, silverlight, xaml, reflection, mvvm

I have a child window which loads xaml dynamically and now I want to do some bindings in order to communicate messages between the child window and the parent. Because the project is plugin-based and it's not possible for the shell, whose only responsibility is loading plugins and helping them to communicate, to determine what controls are in the xaml, it's not sensible to operate them in code behind.

I have implemented a AppDataStore class that stimulates messaging across the whole application.

```
AppDataStore.Values["SomeKey"] = "SomeObject";
```

And thus I'm wondering if it's possible to bind controls loaded dynamically to the viewmodel and consequently in the setter I can use AppDataStore for messaging. Furthermore, it would be perfect if I can implement some validations this way.

You may wonder how come that I try to bind the controls in the circumstance that I do not even know what the controls are. To answer that, I consider it possible if I specify the property I want to bind in the "Tag" property of the control and thus I can iterate through the visual tree and use Reflection to get the property value.

Anyway, above are just some thoughts of mine until now and I have been stuck at this point for long. If you know how to implement it or you have a better solution, please let me know. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could follow an event aggregator/mediator pattern

I have a plugin based project, but the plugins must reference a common framework dll in order to be 'pluggable'. This is one of the best ways to ensure that communication components can be implemented by plugins and the shell application.

In your common framework library:

```
public class Mediator : IMediator // The interface would just specify the methods below
{
    private List<object> _subscribers = new List<object>();

    public void Subscribe(object subscriber)
    {
        _subscribers.Add(subscriber);
    }

    public void Unsubscribe(object subscriber)
    {
        _subscribers.Remove(subscriber);            
    }

    public void Publish(object payload)
    {
        // Loop through all subscribers and see if they implement the interface
        // and that the param types match the passed in payload type
        // if so - call ReceiveMessage with the payload
    }
}
```

The interface that subscribers will use

```
public interface ISubscribe<T>
{
    void ReceiveMessage(T payload);
}
```

Then you just need to pass the mediator around as a dependency

```
public class SomeViewModel, ISubscribe<SomeMessageType>
{
    public SomeViewModel(IMediator mediator)
    {
        mediator.Subscribe(this);
    }

    public ReceiveMessage(SomeMessageType payload)
    {
        // Do stuff with payload            
    }
}
```

The `SomeMessageType` can be any type

This way your messager is a separate component that the plugins can depend on, but all components know how to talk to each other without needing to know about the shell.

They just call `Publish` on the mediator with the message type they want to send:

```
mediator.Publish(new MyMessageType("Hello"));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I use MEF and CM in my project. So messaging isn't quite much of a problem. The problem lies in the fact that it's hard to invoke messaging in code behind because the xaml (dynamical controls) is volatile - although it's me that specify it, I don't want the code to be dependent cause the whole implementation is built on MVVM.

Comment: So why use code-behind - why not just invoke your messaging from the viewmodel? Are you having trouble wiring up controls from the view->viewmodel?

Comment: Yes. Because the xaml controls dynamically loaded might be a TextBox or a CheckBox or whatnot, it's not easy to bind the value in question to the ViewModel. I wish I could bind them all to a Dictionary but not knowing whether it's viable.

Comment: So you are loading your viewmodel in your shell project, and loading your controls from another project - is that correct?

Comment: Precisely speaking, not from another project but from an array of xaml strings, which shall be loaded using XamlReader.

Comment: Ah, that makes things more difficult - but you can still bind commands/actions using control names `<Button x:Name="ClickMe" />` and `public void ClickMe() { // Do Something }` - those bindings should be wired up for you when the XAML content is loaded. Are you trying to stay away from adding caliburn specific action bindings to the XAML:?

Comment: Not really. Implemented this way, the built-in validation mechanism won't be able to be taken advantage of. However, that's absolutely one solution. I have thought of using a value converter as a bridge between the data store shared globally across the application and the child window instead of using a command. The former is a element-based solution while triggering a command of a button takes it as a whole. Still figuring out which way is better. :)